# Three.js .dae model rigging using blender unexpected results

Tags: javascript, blender, three.js

I am creating a rigged model for use in browser using Three.js. Before I rig the model it loads perfectly fine I can move and rotate the model. After I rig the model the pieces load in different locations with unexpected rotations.

I am loading a .dae file type created in blender. The very same file is then rigged which is when the problem occurs.

The pre rigged version is viewable here (just click the play button in menu) 
http://glasnost.itcarlow.ie/~games4/cantwelld/ThreeJS/prototype/prototype.html

The rigged version is viewable here (just click the play button in menu)
http://glasnost.itcarlow.ie/~games4/cantwelld/ThreeJS/prototyperig/prototypeRigged.html

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Is it possible to load a rigged .dae in three.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed manually the "Armature" node of the rigged model file, but nothing changed.

Then I realized that nodes of the first model have fairly transformations like this:

```
<translate sid="location">0 0 0</translate>
<rotate sid="rotationZ">0 0 1 0</rotate>
<rotate sid="rotationY">0 1 0 0</rotate>
<rotate sid="rotationX">1 0 0 90.00001</rotate>
```

But nodes of the second model have a different transformation for each one:

```
<translate sid="location">-0.03634153 0.2361725 0.196658</translate>
<rotate sid="rotationZ">0 0 1 7.848763</rotate>
<rotate sid="rotationY">0 1 0 -7.652335</rotate>
<rotate sid="rotationX">1 0 0 178.5435</rotate>
```

That's the difference.

Comment: Thank you I didn't notice that the points have such strange transformations in the rigged model. Manually changing these to that of the unrigged model draws the model correctly.